# Is it possible to include env file in dist when building vue app

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue 3 and I have an env file that I want to include in the dist folder after I build the app.

Comment: Why would you do that? Can you please explain what´s your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not show in dist folder, but will be accessible inside app. Just create file like:

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

Remember to prefix your variables with `VUE_APP_`